# how can retrieve image in sdcard in byte convertion in android application

Tags: android

I am working in android application retrieve image in sdcard in image read in byte convertion  how can solve this type of problem  i am getting in image uri in sdcard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the question is, but maybe this is how you get a Bitmap from a byte array:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```